# Passing fetched data to context-Provider in react

Tags: reactjs, provider

I am fetching data from a English language dictionary API and creating a front end in react JS. The code works if I render out all components in the Form.js but I am trying to pass returned data to the wordDataContext to create components separately.

```
import React,  {useEffect, useState , useContext  } from 'react';
import {UserContext} from '../context/UserContext';
import {WordContext,WordProvider} from '../context/WordContext';

const getWord = async() => {
  if (word !== '') {
    setWord(word)
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`https://mydictionaryapi.appspot.com/?define=${word}`)
      const data = await response.json()
      iterateObject(data)
      setWordData(data)   // pass to context
      console.log('word data', wordData)  
    } catch(error) {
      let message = "Word NOT Found - Check spellings or connection"
      setMeaning(message)
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
}
```

I am then iterating over the returned dictionary object to extract definitions(meanings), synonyms and example sentence etc.

```
 function iterateObject(data) {
  for (var item in data) {
    if (typeof(data[item]) == "object"){
      if (item === "synonyms"){
        var synonyms = data[item]
        setSynonyms(synonyms)
      }
      iterateObject(data[item])
    }
    else 
    {
      if (item === "definition") {
        var meaning = data[item]
        setMeaning(meaning)
      }
      if (item === "example"){
        var example = data[item]
        setExample(example)
      }
    }    
  }
}
```

I can render out components from iteration but I want to pass the dictionary object ( or iterated items ) to a global wordDataContext to make separate components.  Here is the code for my wordDataContext and Provider,

```
import React, {useState, createContext } from 'react';

export const WordContext = createContext([ [{}], () => {}])

export const WordProvider= (props) => {
    const [wordData , setWordData] = useState({ word:'' , meaning:'', synonyms:{} , example:'' })
    return(
        <WordContext.Provider value={[wordData, setWordData]}>
            {props.children}
        </WordContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Unfortunately, the returned object is not getting passed to the WordDataContext I have tried doing so  after fetching the data in API call function and also when iterating but only get an empty array

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what you describe, but it sounds like you are wanting to update the `wordData` state in `WordProvider` from a nested component. If so, can you share the component that is using the context and trying to update the state?

Comment: Your initial context value doesn't match the initial state shape. One is an array of object while the other is *just* an object. Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we may see how you are consuming and accessing the `WordContext`?